# Can't build android - Multiple dex files

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to build APK for my app using Adobe PhoneGap and I'm getting an error.
I tried it for older versions of my app that the APK building succeeded in the past but I get the same error now.

I'll appreciate any help.
This is what I found in the logs:

```
Running dex in-process requires build tools 23.0.2.
For faster builds update this project to use the latest build tools.
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Comment: did you enable multi dex in gradle??

Comment: are you using `phonegap-facebook-plugin`

Comment: @Tal Try out these plugins - https://github.com/jwall149/cordova-multidex https://github.com/solent/cordova-plugin-multidex

Comment: @MounirElfassi - Yes, i'm using phonegap-facebook-plugin. Can this plugin be the cause for this error?

Comment: please read this : https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/992

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your default config and then invalidate caches and restart your android studio:

```
 // Enabling multidex support.
 multiDexEnabled true
```

If you are running unit tests, you will want to include this in your Application class:

```
public class YouApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```